# Linq2SQL Executes multiple queries for child collections in spite of DataLoadOptions and Projections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm working on a legacy project with ASP.NET MVC (old version) and Linq2SQL among other technologies.

I'm having some trouble with a business entity which has the following structure:

Order

- Has a reference to parent entity DocumentType
- Has a reference to parent entity DocumentSubtype
- Has a reference to parent entity Customer
- Has a reference to parent entity DocumentStatus
- Has a reference to parent entity aspnet_User (CreationUser)
- Has a reference to parent entity aspnet_User (ModificationUser)
- Has a collection of OrderDetails
- Has a collection of OrderDiscounts
- Has a collection of OrderTrackings

This is a part of the code generated by Linq2SQL:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[ORDER]")]
public partial class ORDER : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _OrderID;

    private byte _DocumentTypeID;

    private short _DocumentSubtypeID;

    private byte _BusinessUnitID;

    private string _CustomerID;

    private string _AddressCodeID;

    private string _SalesPersonID;

    private string _SaleConditionID;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _ShippedDate;

    private string _PurchaseOrder;

    private string _OrderComment;

    private byte _State;

    private string _OrderIDGp;

    private System.Nullable<int> _ErrorCode;

    private string _ErrorDesc;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _DateAdd;

    private string _BatchName;

    private System.Nullable<System.Guid> _CreationUserID;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _CreationDate;

    private System.Nullable<System.Guid> _ModificationUserID;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _ModificationDate;

    private System.Nullable<int> _BatchOwner;

    private bool _Multiline;

    private System.Nullable<System.Guid> _DeletionUserID;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _DeletionDate;

    private EntitySet<ORDER_DETAIL> _ORDER_DETAILs;

    private EntitySet<ORDER_TRACKING> _ORDER_TRACKINGs;

    private EntitySet<ORDER_DISCOUNT> _ORDER_DISCOUNTs;

    private EntityRef<aspnet_User> _aspnet_User;

    private EntityRef<aspnet_User> _aspnet_User1;

    private EntityRef<CUSTOMER> _CUSTOMER;

    private EntityRef<DocumentStatus> _DocumentStatus;

    private EntityRef<DocumentType> _DocumentType;

    private EntityRef<DocumentSubtype> _DocumentSubtype;

public ORDER()
    {
        this._ORDER_DETAILs = new EntitySet<ORDER_DETAIL>(new Action<ORDER_DETAIL>(this.attach_ORDER_DETAILs), new Action<ORDER_DETAIL>(this.detach_ORDER_DETAILs));
        this._ORDER_TRACKINGs = new EntitySet<ORDER_TRACKING>(new Action<ORDER_TRACKING>(this.attach_ORDER_TRACKINGs), new Action<ORDER_TRACKING>(this.detach_ORDER_TRACKINGs));
        this._ORDER_DISCOUNTs = new EntitySet<ORDER_DISCOUNT>(new Action<ORDER_DISCOUNT>(this.attach_ORDER_DISCOUNTs), new Action<ORDER_DISCOUNT>(this.detach_ORDER_DISCOUNTs));
        this._aspnet_User = default(EntityRef<aspnet_User>);
        this._aspnet_User1 = default(EntityRef<aspnet_User>);
        this._CUSTOMER = default(EntityRef<CUSTOMER>);
        this._DocumentStatus = default(EntityRef<DocumentStatus>);
        this._DocumentType = default(EntityRef<DocumentType>);
        this._DocumentSubtype = default(EntityRef<DocumentSubtype>);
        OnCreated();
    }
```

I'm trying to execute this method from a service class in order to get all data in a single query. In order to achieve that, at first I tried with DataLoadOptions before injecting the Context into the Repository class but Linq2SQL kept generating one query for each child member in the collections. Then I moved to projections as I've seen in many tutorials, this is the repository modified with that option:

```
        public IEnumerable<ORDER> GetAll(Expression<Func<ORDER, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        var query = _dbContext
                        .ORDERs
                        .AsQueryable();

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        return query
                .Select
                (
                    x => new OrderEntity
                    {
                        OrderID = x.OrderID,
                        DocumentTypeID = x.DocumentTypeID,
                        BusinessUnitID = x.BusinessUnitID,
                        DocumentSubtypeID = x.DocumentSubtypeID,
                        SalesPersonID = x.SalesPersonID,
                        PurchaseOrder = x.PurchaseOrder,
                        SaleConditionID = x.SaleConditionID,
                        CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
                        AddressCodeID = x.AddressCodeID,
                        ShippedDate = x.ShippedDate,
                        OrderComment = x.OrderComment,
                        BatchOwner = x.BatchOwner,
                        Multiline = x.Multiline,
                        State = x.State,
                        OrderIDGp = x.OrderIDGp,
                        BatchName = x.BatchName,
                        ErrorCode = x.ErrorCode,
                        ErrorDesc = x.ErrorDesc,
                        DateAdd = x.DateAdd,
                        CreationUserId = x.CreationUserId,
                        CreationDate = x.CreationDate,
                        ModificationUserId = x.CreationUserId,
                        ModificationDate = x.ModificationDate,
                        DeletionUserId = x.DeletionUserId,
                        DeletionDate = x.DeletionDate,
                        DocumentType = x.DocumentType,
                        DocumentSubtype = x.DocumentSubtype,
                        CUSTOMER = x.CUSTOMER,
                        ORDER_DETAILs = x.ORDER_DETAILs,
                        ORDER_DISCOUNTs = x.ORDER_DISCOUNTs,
                        ORDER_TRACKINGs = x.ORDER_TRACKINGs,
                        DocumentStatus = x.DocumentStatus
                    }
                )
                .ToList();
    }
```

Here is a screenshot from SQL Profiler when I run the above method:

[image]

It keeps generating the same last 3 queries, for every record that fullfills the filter criteria. OrderDetails is part of the main query but i can't do the same with OrderDiscounts and OrderTrackings. I would like to avoid updating to Entity Framework due to time constraints, so any help with this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Replacing navigation properties by join statements may help, but probably not. It's what it is with L2S. Live with it or leave it.

Comment: Do all detail tables have foreign keys?